# SNMP - snmpwalk does not return textual OIDs

Tags: linux, snmp, snmpd

I have snmpd running on an Ubuntu Linux system with a simple /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf:

```
rocommunity public
```

snmpd is listening on localhost. From the same system, I am running:

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public localhost
```

and part of the output is:

```
iso.3.6.1.2.1.92.1.1.1.0 = Gauge32: 1000
iso.3.6.1.2.1.92.1.1.2.0 = Gauge32: 1440
iso.3.6.1.2.1.92.1.2.1.0 = Counter32: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.92.1.2.2.0 = Counter32: 0
```

As you can see, I am only getting numeric OIDs for all but the iso object. I have also tried snmpwalk with the -Of option and snmptranslate. Both produce the exact same OIDs as above: that is, only numeric for children of iso.

Also, there are no other root level objects besides iso. Is that normal?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing the MIB files that do the translation.  To install them run:

apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader

For licensing reasons they arent included by default.  Installing that package will go download the standard ones from the internet.  For specific manufactuer's custom SNMP values you will need to find their .mib files from the manufactuer's website.

Oh and you need to tell snmp to actually use the mibs! Edit /etc/snmp/snmp.conf to read:

mibs +ALL

Comment: Installed this package. Still the same. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Got it working. Had to comment the mibs: line in /etc/snmp/snmp.conf. Thanks

Comment: @wirate yes, i forgot a step.  Added it to the amswer.